# Sync Config and Settings of Atom Editor

Tags: github, atom-editor

I use one windows and one linux machine for my development works. Both places i use Atom editor.

I would like to know is there any way to sync settings/configurations/preferences between my two instances of Atom.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for Atom's [portable mode](http://flight-manual.atom.io/using-atom/sections/basic-customization/#taking-your-customization-with-you-with-portable-mode). By running `atom --portable` you can create a separate settings folder that can then be synced via a storage service like Dropbox or Google Drive.